# How should I apply for a Schengen visa from the UK?

Tags: visas, international-travel, germany, schengen

I’m going to apply for a tourist visa to Germany. It is said that I need a reference letter from my employer. However, I’m working on contract and my contract will end before I go traveling. What should I do?

I’m planning to buy an InterRail rail pass (valid for one month) which can be used in many EU countries. Can this InterRail pass be used as proof as return ticket?

I’m not sure how long I will stay in each country: it depends on how much I like the country. Can I just apply for a visa to visit Germany for one month and book a hotel that can be canceled, and then, decide later how long and in which countries I will travel after I get the visa (within the visa validity period, of course)?

I’m Vietnamese, and hold a post-study work visa.

Comment: What visa are you on in the UK?

Comment: And to add to Ankur's question what's you country of citizenship?

Comment: I'm holding post-study work visa. And I'm Vietnamese.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean *employer*, not *employee*.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this [FAQ](http://www.visafirst.com/en/french_schengen_visa_faq.asp) is pretty exhaustive.  One thing that all countries want to see when you apply for the visa is that you can prove that **you will leave**, so as long as you can show that plus the fact that you can support yourself while you are in the country then you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: thanks Karlson. All the stuff about this visa cost money and time. It would be easier if I could just pack my bag and go.

Comment: @Tuyet If you are looking to enter illegally then this is not the forum to find out how. Unfortunately to do this legally you will need a visa and hence spend time and money getting it

Comment: I have never said that I'm looking to enter illegally. Just a bit of complaining. And as you can see how inconvenient and costly it is as I want to backpack travel, go and stay where and when I want in the given time of the visa.

Comment: @Tuyet I do.  Unfortunately there is no easier way around it...

Comment: Where are you from? USA?

Comment: @Tuyet Thought that was obvious from my profile